# Find rows differences between two tables in oracle 19

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle19c

Hello guys having this query : (***oracle 19***)

```
CREATE TABLE  REGISTRO_LOCAL
   (    ID NUMBER, 
        USUARIO VARCHAR2(20), 
        FECHA_CARGA TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
        fecha date,
        valor number(19,6),
        CONSTRAINT REGISTRO_LOCAL_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE
   );
   
CREATE SEQUENCE   REGISTRO_LOCAL_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 41 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE;
commit;

ALTER TABLE REGISTRO_LOCAL 
MODIFY id DEFAULT REGISTRO_LOCAL_SEQ.nextval;



CREATE TABLE  REGISTRO_API
   (    ID NUMBER, 
        USUARIO VARCHAR2(20), 
        FECHA_CARGA TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
        fecha date,
        valor number(19,6),
        CONSTRAINT REGISTRO_API_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE
   );
   
CREATE SEQUENCE   REGISTRO_API_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 41 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE;
commit;

ALTER TABLE REGISTRO_API 
MODIFY id DEFAULT REGISTRO_API_SEQ.nextval;


Insert into REGISTRO_LOCAL (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('41','bird',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:46:13,416616000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('22/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'23,234');
Insert into REGISTRO_LOCAL (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('42','dog',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:46:13,488931000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('21/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'5,2341');
Insert into REGISTRO_LOCAL (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('43','horse',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:46:31,436053000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('23/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'5');
Insert into REGISTRO_LOCAL (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('44','cat',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:48:22,037646000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('20/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'67,234');
Insert into REGISTRO_LOCAL (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('45','zebra',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:50:04,350761000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('20/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'23');
Insert into REGISTRO_LOCAL (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('46','spider',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:50:49,557596000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('22/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'4');

Insert into REGISTRO_API (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('80','bird',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:46:13,416616000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('22/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'23,234');
Insert into REGISTRO_API (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('81','horse',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:46:31,436053000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('23/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'8');
Insert into REGISTRO_API (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('82','cat',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:48:22,037646000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('21/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'6,234');
Insert into REGISTRO_API (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('83','spider',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:50:49,557596000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('22/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'4');
Insert into REGISTRO_API (ID,USUARIO,FECHA_CARGA,FECHA,VALOR) values ('84','rabbit',to_timestamp('20/08/20 09:50:49,618559000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_date('22/08/20','DD/MM/RR'),'3,867');
```

And using this image:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to identify differences between two tables.

The data that has the last information will be on REGISTRO_API table. Will be ease delete REGISTRO_LOCAL and insert the date from REGISTRO_API.

But my i can't do this.

**1**- I have to do updates over REGISTRO_LOCAL with the new date from REGISTRO_API (this could be a delete and create, not necessary be an UPDATE)

**2**- I have to delete record from REGISTRO_LOCAL when this records doesn't exist on REGISTRO_API

**3**- I have to insert the record that exist on REGISTRO_API and is not on REGISTRO_LOCAL

So which is the best way to do this?

Comment: This can all be handled by a trigger on REGISTRO_API that on create also creates a row in LOCAL, on update it finds that row and updates it. And on delete, it also deletes that row.

Comment: hello , but the problem is LOCAL has data, and API is a process that insert all record at night reading from a rest api. My job now is getting the differences and do the 3 thinks that i have to do.

Comment: What you need then is a scheduled job that executes after API gets filled every night. That just goes through every row in LOCAL and checks it against API, if its there but different, update it. If its not there, delete it. Then also go through API table to check for entries that arent in LOCAL and create them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements you can identify all rows using a "Full Outer Join":

```
select rl.id           rl_id
     , rl.usuario      rl_usuario
     , rl.fecha_carga  rl_fecha_carga
     , rl.fecha        rl_fecha
     , rl.valor        rl_valor
     , ra.id           ra_id
     , ra.usuario      ra_usuario
     , ra.fecha_carga  ra_fecha_carga
     , ra.fecha        ra_fecha
     , ra.valor        ra_valor 
  from registro_local rl
  full outer join registro_api ra
     on ra.usuario = rl.usuario ;
```

Use this a the basis for a procedure to accomplish the updates. Define a cursor for the above query them use Bulk Collect and Forall to do inserts on both local and API tables. Then iterate the collection removing (delete) those items that have been inserted or have not been updated. Depending on data volume you may want to "not updated" check into the query itself. Finally again use Forall to handle updates to local, See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3d9f3e7cf37ce6ec1736110f4d46e19e) for complete example. You can then use your job scheduler, be it Oracle internal or an external scheduler, to run the procedure as needed.

Answer (score 0):

i'm solving this with this way:

First - i do a merge between the two tables
Second - an update over LOCAL TABLE

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

Query:

```
merge into REGISTRO_LOCAL l
using
    (
        select USUARIO
              ,FECHA_CARGA
              ,FECHA
              ,VALOR
        from REGISTRO_API
    ) a
on (
    1=1
    and l.USUARIO = a.USUARIO
    and l.FECHA_CARGA = a.FECHA_CARGA
    and l.FECHA = a.FECHA
    --and l.VAlOR = a.VALOR
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    update set l.VAlOR = a.VALOR
              ,l.ACTION = 'U'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    insert (
         USUARIO
        ,FECHA_CARGA
        ,FECHA
        ,VALOR
        ,ACTION
    )values(
         a.USUARIO
        ,a.FECHA_CARGA
        ,a.FECHA
        ,a.VALOR
        ,'I'
    );
END;

update REGISTRO_LOCAL
set action = 'D'
where action is null;
commit;
```

i hope could be useful for someone else ...

Regards